# PHPUnitTest is not giving result in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony-1.4

I am using 'sfJwtPhpUnitPlugin' plugin for testing my symfony 1.4 project. I followed the steps as below.

Installation : https://github.com/JWT-OSS/sfJwtPhpUnitPlugin/blob/1.0.3/INSTALL.md
Usage : https://github.com/JWT-OSS/sfJwtPhpUnitPlugin/blob/1.0.3/USAGE.md

Automatically generated my test cases.

when I fire the command `./symfony phpunit:unit` I cannot see any result..

.. According to the guide I can see the following statement

```
When running PHPUnit Symfony tasks, JPUP will look for and execute the bootstrap file in sf_test_dir/bootstrap/phpunit.php. If you have any code that needs to be executed before any tests are run, put it in this bootstrap file.
```

But I can not see a file phpunit.php inside test/bootstrap dir. How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the `test/bootstrap/unit.php` and remove the line where lime included. For example my bootstrap file

```
<?php

// configuration
require_once  __DIR__ . '/../../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php';
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::hasActive() ? ProjectConfiguration::getActive() : new ProjectConfiguration();

// autoloader
$autoload = sfSimpleAutoload::getInstance(sfConfig::get('sf_cache_dir').'/project_autoload.cache');
$autoload->loadConfiguration(
    sfFinder::type('file')->name('autoload.yml')->in(
        array(
            sfConfig::get('sf_symfony_lib_dir') . '/config/config',
            sfConfig::get('sf_config_dir'),
        )
    )
);
$autoload->register();
```